# The Efficiency of Views

Tags: android, android-view

If you place many views into an app's layout, there is a threshold (I think 70 views if I remember correctly) that will create an error saying that it is inefficient to have that many views.

Let's say you put 70 `TextView`s in an app's layout - you'll get this warning.

But if you put 10 `TextView`s into a `Custom View` - `TenView` - and put 7 `TenViews`, you don't run into this error, even though the same number of TextViews are being drawn.

Why is it more efficient to wrap multiple views into a Custom View instead of using them individually in the layout file?

Comment: A really efficient way to reduce the View count is when you transform an ImageView which is next to a TextView into a compound drawable (you include the image inside the TextView)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It isn't more efficient. You're just disguising the inefficiency to the point that Android lint tool doesn't recognize the problem.

Perhaps you should rethink your layout. Why do you need 70 text views to start with?

Comment: I would certainly agree that 70 views should be laid out differently, but it's not unthinkable that say a recipe list could have spinners for selecting quantities that would make the views add up quickly  (ingred - whole numb - fraction - unit) * x ingredients with headings, etc. 

But certainly there are numerous apps that use something similar - I don't have any experience with gaming so idk, but Angry Birds seems to have dozens on screen at once. 

I was wondering how it could be more efficient, but hiding the inefficiency was my hypothesis. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @SQLiteNoob - The drop-down for a spinner is actually a distinct popup window, so the views for the options are not part of the app's main layout. As for games like Angry Birds, I don't have any first-hand knowledge of their design, but most of them probably use a single [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) to display most of the game content. They can then build light-weight widgets for the game elements rather than relying on Android `View` objects, which are rather heavyweight objects.